# Reference function within package matlab

Tags: matlab, namespaces, editor, projects-and-solutions

I would like to structure my project in several packages. Each package should be each own namespace (so as to avoid conflicting filename) but within a package, I want everything to be in the same namespace (without having to put all the files in the same folder; I'd like different folders).

In practice I would like this structure

```
Project 
    main.m
    commonLibrary
    +part1Project
        mainPart1.m
        otherFolder
            supportFile.m
    +part2Project
        mainPart2.m
        otherFolder2
            supportFile2.m
```

This is the behavious I would like:

- When in main.m, I can call everything in common library and everything in any sub-project, including the functions inside the subfolder. So I would like to call part1Project.supportFile
- When in mainPart1.m, I want to call the support files without using the prefix of the current package (i.e. I want to call supportFile directly)
- When in mainPart2, I want to call supportFile2 directly. If I want access to files in the the part 1 of the project, I can call part1Project.supportFile.

The current setup is that I added the Project folder and all the subfolders to the matlab path. But this means that

- I CANNOT call supportFile from anywhere; not from main (part1Project.supportFile will not work) and not even from mainPart1 (supportFile can't be found)
- Much in the same way, it is hard to access elements of part1Project from part2Project

How can I achieve the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access functions within a subfolder of a package unless that subfolder is a [private folder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) in which case it will only be accessible to the functions in the immediate parent folder.

If you do use the `private` folder approach, then you can call functions within this `private` folder from the functions in the containing folder without using the fully-qualified package name.

Your layout would look like:

```
Project 
    main.m
    commonLibrary
    +part1Project
        mainPart1.m
        private
            supportFile.m
    +part2Project
        mainPart2.m
        private
            supportFile2.m
```

Your first point will *not* work but the other two will. There is no built-in way to accomplish the first point.

Another option would be to use `import` statements in all functions within each package such that it imports all package members at the beginning of the function.

Your layout would look like

```
Project 
    main.m
    commonLibrary
    +part1Project
        mainPart1.m
        supportFile.m
    +part2Project
        mainPart2.m
        supportFile2.m
```

And the contents of `mainPart1.m` (any any function) would look something like:

```
function mainPart1()
    % Import the entire namespace
    import part1Project.*

    % No package name required
    supportFile()
end
```

And then from `main` you could access `supportFile`

```
function main() 
    part1Project.supportFile()
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So either I use private folders (no way of calling the functions outside the package) or I put everything in the same folder in the package and then use the import at the start of mainPart1. I don't mind to use the import, but I would really like to keep the packages tidy by using sub-folder for each group of functions. So there is no way of doing it? Or can I create sub-packages, such that I can call part1Project.subpart1.supportfile?

Comment: @Ant Yes those are the possible routes. Subpackages would be another option. Needless to say, MATLAB's package capabilities could use a major overhaul. It's also worth noting that `private` folder cannot contain  classes

Comment: It sure looks like it. Thanks a lot :)